# Functions php shortcode for displaying main menu with no child items

Tags: functions, theme-development, menus

I have the following simple `functions.php` snippet to generate a shortcode which will add a menu to a Wordpress site. I would like to do two new things so that I can use this in a footer. I'm lazy and don't want to create a footer menu ;)

I need to:

1. Filter off the Homepage
2. Show only the top-level parent items and no child pages

```php
// Show Footer Menu
function print_menu_shortcode($atts, $content = null) {
extract(shortcode_atts(array( 
                             'name' => null, 
                            'class' => null ), $atts));
return wp_nav_menu( array( 
                         'menu' => $name, 
                         'menu_class' => 'footer-menu', 
                         'echo' => false ) );
}

add_shortcode('menu', 'print_menu_shortcode');
```

Answer (score 1):

You could set the `'depth'` argument to `1` in your `wp_nav_menu()` call to get only top level items, along with the custom menu walker, something like this:

```
return wp_nav_menu( array( 'menu' => $name, 'menu_class' => 'footer-menu', 'echo' => false, 'depth' => 1, 'walker' => new custom_footer_menu_walker ) );
```

Add the custom menu walker to your functions.php (12345 is the ID of your homepage, that should be excluded):

```
class custom_footer_menu_walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {

    function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {

        parent::start_el($item_html, $item, $depth, $args);

        $exclude = array();
        $exclude[] = 12345;

        if ( ! in_array( $item->object_id, $exclude ) ) {
            $output .= $item_html;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, that looks good but how do I also create all of this as a shortcode?

Comment: You already did. Just replace your return statement with mine, in your `print_menu_shortcode` function. Then you can call the [menu] shortcode wherever you need to.